# Why is my backround image is not working in css?+

Tags: html, css, image, background

so I had this problem that makes me impatient
this is my code.

```
    .column {float: left;}



.column.side {width: 25%;}



.column.middle {width: 50%;}

.row:after {content:"";
    Display: table;
    clear:both;}
   
.column.middle p {backround-color:#58bf96;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:20px;}
      
.column.middle img {padding-top:20px;}

body {backround-image: url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/black-galaxy.jpg');

backround-repeat: no-repeat;

backround-size: cover;}
```

even I copied my teacher's example, it is still white background.
Anyone help me here?

Comment: Your code is so badly formatted that it is nearly impossible to find problems. You will find debugging much easier if you structure your CSS code with balanced parenthesis and indentation.  See [the importance of indentation](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/132/4974)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

You background spelling was wrong & you need to also give width and height with background as given below:-

```css
body {background: url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/7563778.jpg'); width:100vw; height:100vh; background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: cover;}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your link is not correct. I mean there is no image in that link(https://wallpaperaccess.com/black-galaxy.jpg)...
After that your tag name is wrong..

Use **background** instead of *backround*

Then run again and it will be working fine.

```css
    body {
      background-image: url("https://wallpaperaccess.com/thumb/1457543.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```